# Stitch BublCam photos

Tags: 360-panorama, image-stitching

I have to stitch and HDR a lot of photos taken using the Bublcam camera. These photos contains the 4 fisheyes captures in a multiplex format. The lenses can't be moved on the camera and they will always have the same position. I have 3 photos per HDR.

Here is an example file, [H12M0052.JPG](http://i.imgsafe.org/bbf4148.jpg)
[image]

Here are the other exposures:

- [H12H0053.JPG](http://i.imgsafe.org/bd5fec4.jpg)
- [H12L0054.JPG](http://i.imgsafe.org/bef3aac.jpg)

As I plan to do develop a program to batch this process, it would be great if the stitching software could be used in command-line. Is there any stitching software best suited for this kind of job? How many control-point would you recommand to place in order to have the most accurate stitch? Any other advice is welcome.

**Note:** I don't want to use the "stitch in the cloud" feature provided by Bubl as some of the images taken will be confidential to our company.

---

**Edit:**

I expect the output to be an equirectangular projection of the panorama.
Example:
[image: Output example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a stiching project in [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) and use it repeatedly to process any photos via command line, as described in the [PanoTools wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/Panorama_scripting_in_a_nutshell#Simple_command-line_stitching):

> This example takes a pre-existing project called template.pto, created
>   with three photos. It uses nona for remapping, and enblend for
>   blending the remapped photos into a finished TIFF image:

```
nona -o out -m TIFF_m template.pto DSC_1234.JPG DSC_1235.JPG DSC_1236.JPG
enblend -o finished.tif out0000.tif out0001.tif out0002.tif
```

In the BublCam case, the first step should be probably cutting the source image into 4 separate views ([ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can help).